# Can inheritance be used with Codea?

Tags: inheritance, lua, codea

Is it possible to use inheritance with [Codea](http://twolivesleft.com/Codea/)? While I am fairly new to Lua, but from some quick Googling, it looks like [the methods](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ObjectOrientationClosureApproach) to do [inheritance and polymorphism](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ObjectOrientationClosureApproach) are a bit "[involved](http://lua-users.org/wiki/MetamethodsTutorial)". Is there any technique that can be used safely with Codea's Lua-hosting engine?

---

Here is a simple runnable test I am trying to get working. My superclass:

```
Superklass = class()

function Superklass:init(x,y)
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
end

function Superklass:debug()
    print(string.format("(%d, %d)", self.x, self.y))
end
```

A subclass:

```
Ship = class()

function Ship:init(x, y)
    -- you can accept and set parameters here
    print('ship:init() called')

    self = Superklass(x,y) -- ???
    print('attempting to call self:debug()')
    self:debug() -- works! prints  
    print('ok!')
end

function Ship:draw()
    print('ship:draw() called')
    
    print('attempting to call self:debug()')
    self:debug()
    print('ok')
end
```

And the program entrypoint:

```
-- initial setup
function setup()
    ship = Ship(HEIGHT/2, WIDTH/2)
end

-- called once every frame
function draw()
    ship:draw()
end
```

---

Here's the output from running that:

```
ship:init() called
attempting to call self:debug()
(384, 375)
ok!
ship:draw() called
attempting to call self:debug()
error: [string "Ship = class()..."]:16: attempt to call method 'debug' (a nil value)
Pausing playback
```

I am sure this is incredibly naive -- but I would love a tip in the direction of something that might work in the context of Codea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to give a working solution (class inheritance in Codea) and point out a few of the pitfalls. First, I should note that Codea loads classes in tab order, so the tabs for the superclasses have to be *prior to* the tabs for the subclasses. I would recommend looking through [this thread on the Codea forums](http://twolivesleft.com/Codea/Talk/discussion/96/class-inheritances/p1). It discusses the technique below, and also gives some insight into the underlying mechanics.

First, we define a superclass *AbstractSprite* whose constructor takes an (x,y) coordinate. It provides a method **debug** to echo this coordinate to the console.

```
AbstractSprite = class()

function AbstractSprite:init(x,y)
    self.position = vec2(x,y)
    
    print("new AbstractSprite created")
end

function AbstractSprite:debug()
    print(string.format("(%d,%d)", self.position.x, self.position.y))
end
```

Next, we define an implementing class *Ship*, which implements a custom **debug** that calls *super*, demonstrating how to move up the class hierarchy.

```
Ship = class(AbstractSprite)

function Ship:init()
    AbstractSprite.init(self)
    print("new Ship created")
end

function Ship:debug()
    print("I am a ship, calling my superclasses' methods!")
    AbstractSprite.debug(self)
end
```

The program entrypoint. We create both a *Ship* and a 'raw' *AbstractSprite*, calling debug on each:

```
function setup()
    ship = Ship()
    ship:debug()
    
    asteroid = AbstractSprite(150, 200)
    asteroid:debug()
end
```

And console output:

```
new AbstractSprite created
new Ship created
I am a ship, calling my superclasses' methods!
(0,0)
new AbstractSprite created
(150,200)
```

Comment: Codea doesn't necessarily load the files alphabetically. It loads them in the order in which the file 'tabs' are displayed. This **usually** corresponds to alphabetical order but can lead to odd behavior if you don't realize this (there is a brief mention of this at the bottom of the linked Codea forum discussion).

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I'm the author of [middleclass](http://github.com/kikito/middleclass), an OO-lib for Lua.

The closure-based you pointed out on the first example is a nice intellectual exercise, but it has little practical value. In Lua, object orientation is better achieved with tables (as the example pointed out by your second example suggests) - it gives equivalent functionality at a faster rate. The only differences are syntactical.

There are lots of libraries that use the standard table-based approach to do OO in Lua. You may find a list here:

http://lua-users.org/wiki/ObjectOrientedProgramming

Using middleclass, your code would become like this:

```
require 'middleclass'

-- middleclass needs the class name as a parameter
SuperClass = class('SuperClass') -- I don't see the point of using a K here, BTW

function SuperClass:initialize(x,y) -- initialize instead of init
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
end

function SuperClass:debug()
    print(string.format("(%d, %d)", self.x, self.y))
end
--

Ship = class('Ship', SuperClass) -- notice that we put the superclass here

function Ship:initialize(x, y) -- initialize instead of init again
    -- you can accept and set parameters here
    print('ship:initialize() called')

    self = SuperClass.initialize(self,x,y) -- notice the extra self and initialize here
    print('attempting to call self:debug()')
    self:debug() -- works! prints  
    print('ok!')
end

function Ship:draw()
    print('ship:draw() called')

    print('attempting to call self:debug()')
    self:debug()
    print('ok')
end
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Would you happen to have tried using this in the context of Codea?

Comment: Just for future googlers, I have found this which lays it out pretty well: http://twolivesleft.com/Codea/Talk/discussion/96/class-inheritances/p1

Comment: @kikito I'm getting this error in your example "attempt to index local 'self' (a nil value)". This happens in the line `self = SuperClass.initialize(self,x,y)`. I'm using Corona SDK. Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Comment: You are probably invoking a class creator with `MyClass.new(params)` instead of `MyClass:new(params)`